# I'm learning about Java factory methods and want to know how to implement the example provided

Tags: java, factory-pattern

Im reading Cracking The Coding Interview. In the section on Object Oriented Design they describe Factory Methods. They give an example but when I put this into eclipse it fails because `GameType` hasn't been defined. How would I implement this class?

### Example Java Code

```
public class CardGame {
    public static CardGame createCardGame(GameType type) {
        if (type == GameType.Poker) {
            return new PokerGame();
        } else if (type == GameType.BlackJack) {
            return new BlackJackGame();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: GameType would be a separate class source file.  From this limited example it looks like it would be an Enum.

Comment: `GameType` looks like an enum or a class with something that simulate an enum, so I would do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GameType` looks like an enum or a class with something that simulate an enum, so I would do that. So it will be something like :

```
public enum GameType {
    Poker, BlackJack;
}
```

Which give something like in your example :

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GameType type = GameType.Poker;
    }

}
```